# Desktop graphics - or "skinned" windows

Tags: python, graphics, desktop, skinning, shaped-window

I'm looking for a way to draw animations right on the desktop. No window frames and with transparent background.

I'm using Python in windows XP for it, but it doesn't have to be cross platform, although it'd be a nice bonus.

Does anyone know about a python library that can do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550001/fully-transparent-windows-in-pygame

Answer (score 2):

If you want a frameless window, there are several options. For example, pygame can be initialized with the following flag:

```
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size=(640,480), pygame.NOFRAME)
```

Your question doesn't make it clear if you're looking for a transparent surface, though.

Comment: I guess I was a bit presumptuous there. Yes, I'm looking for a transparent window without borders.