# Make a window transparent using Win32?

Tags: python, windows, winapi, pywin32, pywin

Using Python Win32 extensions, how do you make an arbitrary window on Windows XP transparent?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[SetLayeredWindowsAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633540.aspx) example:

```
import win32gui
import win32con
import winxpgui
import win32api
import subprocess
import time

subprocess.Popen("notepad.exe", shell=True)
time.sleep(1)
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "New file - metapad")  ## The caption of my empty notepad (MetaPad)

win32gui.SetWindowLong (hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE, win32gui.GetWindowLong (hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE ) | win32con.WS_EX_LAYERED )
winxpgui.SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, win32api.RGB(0,0,0), 180, win32con.LWA_ALPHA)
```

Comment: You can eliminate the `winxpgui` import by using `win32gui.SetLayeredWindowAttributes()`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [SetLayeredWindowAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) **WIN32 API function** for creating transparent windows:

```
BOOL WINAPI SetLayeredWindowAttributes(
  __in  HWND hwnd,
  __in  COLORREF crKey,
  __in  BYTE bAlpha,
  __in  DWORD dwFlags
);
```

[Here](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/frameworks/advancedui/windowingtechniquesandclasses/article.php/c3213) is a code sample that you can use for wrapping WIN32 API functions for setting transparency.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import win32gui
import win32con
import winxpgui
import win32api
import subprocess
import time

subprocess.Popen("notepad.exe", shell=True)
time.sleep(1)
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "New file - metapad")  ## The caption of my empty notepad (MetaPad)

win32gui.SetWindowLong (hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE, win32gui.GetWindowLong (hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE ) | win32con.WS_EX_LAYERED )
winxpgui.SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, win32api.RGB(0,0,0), 180, win32con.LWA_ALPHA)
```

This does not work for Windows 10.

Comment: Yes it does. I just tested it. 
In fact it even works on Windows 11