# Pygame transparent background

Tags: pygame

I'm using Pygame and I'm trying to make the background transparent instead of black,
 something like wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND in wxpython, I did remove the borders (pygame.NOFRAME), so any clues?

Comment: You want to have a window that will show you what is underneath?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. Pygame uses [SDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_DirectMedia_Layer), which does not allow seeing through windows to the desktop.

However if you use Linux, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10399831/3532849) answer may help you to create the illusion of transparency.

Comment: Thank you, the link was very helpful! I've been trying to figure out how to do this for a long time!